# Mysql Replication Error: Waiting for master to send event

Tags: mysql, linux, replication

My replica db can't update master update.

When I write on my replica

`Show slave status\g`

its result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: MASTERIP
                  Master_User: replicatest
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000018
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 154
               Relay_Log_File: vf-db-replica-relay-bin.000052
                Relay_Log_Pos: 320
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000018
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 1
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 154
              Relay_Log_Space: 748
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 81d41160-5197-11ea-a060-005056ae75b8
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also, when I write on my replica `show master status\g`

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB                                | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.001041 |      154 |              | information_schema,mysql,performance_schema,sys |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When on my master db I write `show master status\g`

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000018 |      154 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I guess, problem is mysql-bin file.

How can I solve this replication error?

Comment: Why are you writing on the replica? Writes should be done on master.

Comment: Why do you think there is an error?

Comment: @mustaccio because my replica db 38.8gb master db 45.3gb

Comment: Why do you consider this an error?

Answer (score 0):

The replica db isn't necessarily the same size as its source. Rows are stored where they fit, and this can lead to different fragmentation patterns in the tablespace files over time. So even if they both store the same rows, the physical size on disk might be quite different.

You also said in a comment (before this question was migrated from Stack Overflow to this site) that two months of data is missing from the replica. This is definitely a bigger problem than a tablespace file size difference.

If the replica has lost its fidelity, that is, the data on the replica isn't a true replica of the source, then the simplest solution is to reinitialize the replica.

---

It's easy to recreate a replica. Make a new backup of the source, and include backup of the binary log coordinates (unless you use GTID with auto positioning). Stop replication on the replica and restore the backup you just made. Then reconfigure replication and start it.

That way you know the data is logically identical to the moment you created the backup on the source, and hopefully replication will continue without error from that point on.

At my last job, my team managed thousands of replicated MySQL instances, and we had to reinitialize replicas in this way every week.

We used Percona XtraBackup to make a physical backup of the source, then transfer that backup to the replica server, and use it to replace the datadir of the replica MySQL instance. XtraBackup includes the binary log coordinates by default, saved in a small text file.

The documentation for XtraBackup includes a short guide on how to do this: https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/howtos/setting_up_replication.html

---

A complete reinitialization might seem too time-consuming or too much work. If you think only a small amount of the data is in need of repair, you could use a tool to find the minimal set of rows needed on the replica to bring it into true with respect to the source.

Percona makes a free tool to do this: [pt-table-sync](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html).